# Facebook API, how to use object_attachment in scheduled publish posts?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I creating personal application from Facebook Graph, and can't find any examples: how to attach my local picture from (my fan-page, when I'am admin) to  scheduled publish posts. Without pictures - post is delay in time fine. If I want to publish with pictures now same fine. I'm report to .facebook.com/bugs/ and get answer "use object_attachment", but how to use, I don't now(

My query:

[https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=POST&path=**id_page_**%2Ffeed&version=v2.8&message=text_delay&scheduled_publish_time=1486755500&published=false&object_attachment=194418771038550](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=POST&path=__id_page___%2Ffeed&version=v2.8&message=text_delay&scheduled_publish_time=1486755500&published=false&object_attachment=194418771038550) + token_page

What it's wrong??
p.s. I have all markes and do in Graph API Explorer 
p.s.s. success upload (to fan_page) image and get id

Comment: I am having this exact issue as well. Are you getting a "An unknown error has occured" in the HTTP response from Facebook too?

Comment: stevemanuel: yes, I'm  getting error code "1" "An unknown error has occurred". Today, from facebook.com/bugs/ I received this:
"object_attachment is a string of Facebook ID for an existing picture in the person's photo albums to use as the thumbnail image. They must be the owner of the photo, and the photo cannot be part of a message attachment. I don't think 194418771038550 is a valid object_attachment here because it is not yet existing."

Comment: My error code is the same. However, I am using a real object_attachment from an upload that was just completed previously. I can verify that the object_attachment is valid, but am still getting this error.

Comment: stevemanuel I answer below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/feed` edge does not support the `object_attachment` parameter when scheduling a post - it is deprecated (though still documented with no mention of its deprecation), according to this Facebook Bug Report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1160824890650326/

Despite the documentation clearly listing it as a parameter, the process to post a photo or video is to use the `/photos` or `/videos` edge instead, and pass `published=false` and `scheduled_publish_time=xxxxxxxxxx` parameters. The `message` parameter becomes `caption` for a photo, and a `description` for a video.

This way you don't need to first upload the photo/video and then use it's ID in an additional request.

Here is the documentation for a photo post, since your question is specific to a photo:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/photos/#Creating

---

In the format you have shared, the updated request would look like:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=POST&path=id_page_%2Fphotos&version=v2.8&caption=text_delay&scheduled_publish_time=1486755500&published=false&url=http://example.com/image.png + token_page

Answer (score 3):

Multiple images in single post for the planned publication:
first:
you need upload each photo to: URL_GRAPH + "/" + page_id + "/photos 
with fields:
"published=false" and "access_token=your_acces_token_page"
then you got id image

second:
[click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X33hi.jpg)

....cebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=POST&path=page_id%2Ffeed&version=v2.8&attached_media[0]=%7B"media_fbid"%3A"200293027117791"%7D&attached_media[1]= %7B"media_fbid"%3A"200293223784438"%7D&message=sadasd&scheduled_publish_time=1487624100&published=false + page_token

UPD:

so this is work... (through Explorer...)

 https://yadi.sk/i/zkJFg2lj3EGs8z

 https://yadi.sk/i/6poalYCD3EGs9b

Comment: That is helpful to know -- thank you for adding. I have seen no documentation of the `attached_media` parameter.. where did you discover this?

Comment: stevemanuel  - finger to the sky))) Many times tried)
note: in graph explorer (attach img) - it cut attached_media[0] and attached_media[1] for one attached_media, but you should in your request add fileds as: attached_media[0]={"media_fbid":"some_id"} and attached_media[1]={"media_fbid":"some_id""}